# How to calculate aggregate function SUM on an alias column?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to calculate aggregate function SUM on an alias column?

```
SELECT a.question_id, 
       a.level, 
       Count(a.question_id) AS rank, 
       Sum(rank)        AS total 
FROM   logs AS a, 
       question AS b 
WHERE  a.question_id = b.q_id 
       AND a.level = '2' 
GROUP  BY a.question_id 
ORDER  BY rank DESC
```

Comment: You could use a sub-query. Good luck!

Comment: `SUM(COUNT(a.step_id)) AS total`. Aliases are only available in GROUP BY, ORDER BY or HAVING (aside from direct output).

Comment: please give me example.. ;)

Comment: You are declaring `GROUP BY a.question_id` and also COUNT() and SUM() on the same field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply wrap your reused alias with (SELECT alias) :

```
SELECT a.question_id, 
       a.level, 
       COUNT(a.question_id) AS rank, 
       SUM(SELECT(rank)) AS total 
FROM   logs AS a, 
       question AS b 
WHERE  a.question_id = b.q_id 
       AND a.level = '2' 
GROUP  BY a.question_id 
ORDER  BY rank DESC
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT(...)) AS ... at line_1'

Comment: i am not sure why this answer is accepted and so many upvotes. its giving error syntax error

Comment: Maybe because this answer is almost 7 years old, and you may have a recent MySQL version.

Answer (score 6):

The scoping rules of SQL do not allow you to use an alias in the same `select`.  Although this seems unreasonable, it is to prevent confusions such as:

```
select 2*x as x, x+1
```

Which `x` does the second variable refer to?

You can solve this problem by using a subquery:

```
select t.*, Sum(rank) AS total 
from (SELECT a.question_id, a.level, Count(a.question_id) AS rank, 
      FROM logs AS a join
           question AS b 
           on a.question_id = b.q_id 
      WHERE a.level = '2' 
      GROUP  BY a.question_id 
     ) t
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

I also fixed your join syntax.  The use of a comma to mean a `cross join` with restrictions in the `where` clause is rather outdated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to do this unless you have a different grouping for `SUM(rank)` than you would for `COUNT(a.question_id)`.  Otherwise, the SUM will always be working on one row - which is the value of the result of COUNT.  Moreover, you are asking for `COUNT(a.question_id)` where you have specified the GROUP BY clause to also use `a.question_id`.  This is not going to return the results you are looking for.

If you clarify what your grouping would be for `rank`, a subquery could be made for this.